# [parser setDelegate:self];

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml

```
NSString* username = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"username_preference"];
NSString* accountPassword = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"password_preference"];
NSString* urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://%@:%@@testing.com/test.php",username,accountPassword];    
NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *) response;

int status = [httpResponse statusCode];
if (!((status >= 200) && (status < 300))) {
    NSLog(@"Connection failed with status %@", status);
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
} else {
    NSXMLParser* xmlparser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData: response];
    NSLog(@"at parser %@", xmlparser);
    [parser setDelegate:self];
```

The last line of the code is showing me error and suggest that "change parser to pause"!! Please help!!

Comment: You click the check-mark next to the answer that you found answered your question.

Answer (score 2):

Well, isn't that because your parser variable is named 'xmlparser' and not 'parser' ?

Comment: Even if I set it to xmlparser, it will show the same error. BTW, do we have to implement or include some other .h class in our .m or .h class in order to use XMLParser ??

Comment: Yeah, maybe you have to import "NSXMLParser.h"

Comment: Thanks for your help, include <NSXMLParser.h> removed the error, now I have another problem...it says "class myclass does not implement the NSXMLParserDelegate protocol"....

Comment: That is because you assigned the class to be delegate of the NSXMLParser. In order to do that you .h file must state that it is a NSXMLParserDelegate. Something like `@interface MyClass : NSObject <NSXMLParserDelegate>{...}`

Comment: But now I have a very different error, I put include <NSXMLParser.h> in my .m file it says include NSXMLParser.h not found

Comment: Maybe my memory serves me wrong, and NSXMLParser is included in the main framework. Then there is no need to import it. Can't really remember.

Answer (score 1):

Change `parser` to `xmlparser`.

Comment: Even if I set it to xmlparser, it will show the same error. BTW, do we have to implement or include some other .h class in our .m or .h class in order to use XMLParser ??